# How to use javascript to add target="_blank" to some links only?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use javascript to add `target="_blank"` to all links that include the following in the URL: `profile.php?id=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var aElems = document.links;

for (var i=0,len = aElems.length; i<len; i++){
    if (aElems[i].href.indexOf('profile.php?id=') != -1){
        aElems[i].target = '_blank';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J2szZ/).

---

**Edited** to improve the performance of the above code, removing `document.links` and replacing it with `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`:

```
var aElems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0,len = aElems.length; i<len; i++){
    if (aElems[i].href.indexOf('profile.php?id=') != -1){
        aElems[i].target = '_blank';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J2szZ/1/).

---

It's worth noting, though, that using [Chris Fulstow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556013/82548)'s `querySelectorAll()`-enabled `$('a[href*="profile.php?id="]')` approach is marginally faster (in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04): [JS Perf speed-test](http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test/2). Therefore, the following is the fastest (in browsers that support `querySelectorAll()`):

```
var aElems = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="profile.php?id="]');

for (var i=0,len = aElems.length; i<len; i++){
    if (aElems[i].href.indexOf('profile.php?id=') != -1){
        aElems[i].target = '_blank';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J2szZ/2/).

Above assertion 'fastest' supported by [JS Perf comparison](http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test/2), at least in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04. Bear in mind, of course, that [IE < 8, and Firefox 3](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13), aren't going to play well with this approach.

Of course, the above should be corrected to:

```
var aElems = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="profile.php?id="]');

for (var i=0,len = aElems.length; i<len; i++){
    aElems[i].target = '_blank';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J2szZ/3/).

This is because the `if` condition was already evaluated by `querySelectorAll()`, which makes the `if` entirely redundant.

Modified [JS Perf comparison: http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test/3](http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test/3).

Comment: I'll give a +1 here for a native JS solution.

Comment: Why, thank you! (And, seriously, I wasn't trying to dismiss your answer in my comment, it's just that you posted jQuery code without explaining that it was jQuery...which if he didn't know about jQuery would've seemed confusing when it didn't work. Sorry.).

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Another jQuery solution, just for fun.

```
$("a[href*='profile.php?id=']").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) or look at their [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) and port their logic into your own code base:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('href').indexOf('profile.php?id=') !== -1) {
            $this.attr('target','_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KJv7D/

Comment: Meh. I imagine if the OP knew about JQuery he wouldn't be asking such a simple question.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, since you explained that your answer is, and linked to, jQuery. +1 for the answer.

Comment: *If* he was to use jQuery, a better solution would be `$('a[href*="profile.php?id="]').prop('target','_blank');` And if OP doesn't know how to do this simple task, looking at jQuery's source won't be much help.

Comment: `$('a[href*="profile.php?id="]')` is a valid `qSA` selector, so Sizzle wouldn't be used in most browsers. And in non-`qSA` browsers, Sizzle will use `gEBTN`, then will do the filter you're doing, avoiding the need to create a new jQuery object for each `<a>` element. And if you were going for performance, you would have done `$(document.links)`. And since we're in JavaScript, we should really be dealing with properties instead of attributes. So yep, I'd say I did a pretty good job.

Comment: I'm curious, but don't have time right now to check for myself, but was does [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com) say about the different approaches?

Comment: I stand corrected - SmartAssFred's answer is about 300% faster than both of ours (on Chrome/Mac) @DavidThomas :) http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test

Comment: It's always good to learn something new, and interestingly (to me!) it's faster to use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` than `document.links` (something I'd suspected, but never tested...): http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test/2 =)

Comment: @DavidThomas: Interesting about `document.links`, but I was *really* surprised to see that the 1 line jQuery solution was faster than the `qSA` solution. But then I realized that you included `if (aElems[i].href.indexOf('profile.php?id=') != -1)`, which wouldn't be necessary since we already applied that filter in the `qSA` selector. Removing it gives a result more like I expected. http://jsperf.com/anchor-selector-test/3/

Comment: Ah, AlienWebguy deleted his comment so he could conceal who the true smart-ass was. That's just funny... Unless you're really *Jean-Claude Van Damme*, in which case I'd have to say that it was a very wise and cunning move, sir. ;)

Comment: @RightSaidFred: good catch! =) Man, I love JS Perf sometimes..!

Comment: @RightSaidFred I am in spirit, in the deep unhealthy idolization sort of way.